# Callout Annotation in MapInfo

Tags: labeling, mapinfo, annotation

Is there any way to use callout windows or boxes in MapInfo with lead lines to label a point layer?

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck?  Which version are you using?  Are you looking for more than is covered in the existing [MapInfo Idea](http://pbinsight.force.com/pbideas/ideaView?id=087800000001GBNAA2)?

Answer (score 3):

The callout lines are somewhat limited in MapInfo.  Below is a screenshot of MapInfo 12.5 64-bit (but this is the same in most recent 32-bit versions as well).

You can create label lines, but the caveat is that they don't appear until you physically move the label.
[image]

You can see I have moved points 5 and 6 in the below image.
[image]

Once you've created the custom label by moving it and generating the line, you can also double click on the label and edit it as you need to.

In the below image, I've edited point 6 and changed the styles to a green box.

[image]

That's about all you can do unless you write a MapBasic program to create the graphical elements.

Comment: For regions, labels can be moved outside and have a label line added automatically. You can use this knowledge by buffering your points and in this way have the labels moved outside automatically

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an existing [MapInfo Idea](http://pbinsight.force.com/pbideas/ideaView?id=087800000001GBNAA2) for **More options in MapInfo to allow for annotations (“callouts”)**, which suggests to me that it may not currently be possible.